# How to find element with Android uiautomator?

Tags: android, python, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm using android uiautomator with Python and Appium. I have the following element and I need to find a way to click on it. The element have no unique resourceId, className or text.

[The image of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKXyj.png)

[The elements details on the uiautomator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtwB2.png)

Comment: Hi Please use appium inspector : https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

Comment: Add a screenshot of the properties section of the uiautomator to your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Appium-Inspector](http://appium.io/downloads.html) the get the xPath of the button and then locate the button via xPath:

`btn1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath-here")`